# Community site: manually change order of forum categories

Tags: sharepoint-online, list-view, community-site

SharePoint automatically sorts the categories of a community site alphabetically. I would like to set a custom order.

My idea was to add a hidden column "order" in which you enter a number and then sort the view by that column. The problem is that the only view which I can actually modify is the admin view, but not the default view with the tiles.

Any idea either how to modify the default view or how to achieve the custom order differently?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to create a new column, and then edit the view so that the items are displayed in the order set in the new column:
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your contribution Elsie. This is what I have tried initially. The problem is that you can only change the view to manage the categories but I did not find a way to change the view which shows the category to the user. It is categories in a Sharepoint community forum template.